# Firebase - How to insert the current date in the Timestamp field inside an array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> "FieldValue.serverTimestamp() cannot be used inside of an array"

Is there any way to add the current date in a Timestamp field within an array?
The structure of the collection is:

nameCollection (collection): 
                              nameDocument (document | array | map) [ 
                 - **date (Timestamp);** 
                 - origin (string); 
                 - quantity(number); 
                              ]; 
                              (...)

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
...
array.nameDocument.push({
        date: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        origin: "xxx",
        quantity: 10
    });
```

Comment: You quoted in your question that "FieldValue.serverTimestamp() cannot be used inside of an array".  It seems to me that you already know the limitation here.

Comment: You're asking two different things (I think): A [FieldValue.serverTimestamp() ](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-servertimestamp) is a placeholder for a server-generated timestamp. On the other hand, a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) is a type of field that represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution. Don't get the two confused and yes, you can use the Timestamp FIELD anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
...
array.nameDocument.push({
    date: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
    origin: "xxx",
    quantity: 10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For java it's like this `Timestamp.now()`. Should be very similar in `JS`. Check the following [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp).